# CMake cannot find OpenMP

Tags: cmake, openmp

I am trying to compile with OpenMP. My `CMakeLists.txt` contains the line

`find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)`

and CMake errors out with

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package openmp.

  Set openmp_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
  openmp.  The file will have one of the following names:

    openmpConfig.cmake
    openmp-config.cmake
```

Checking my filesystem, I see that I have `/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake` but no `openmpConfig.cmake` or `openmp-config.cmake`. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OpenMp` is not a package, if it's supported, it comes as a part of the your compiler. Try setting `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` or `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` accordingly. e.g:

`set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fopenmp")` activates `OpenMP` for compiling `C` sources when `gcc` is used. For other compilers, you should first detect the compiler and then add appropriate flags

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134660/how-to-apply-different-compiler-options-for-different-compilers-in-cmake had an interesting solution in which CMake checks if the flag is supported using a macro.  Sort of the logical expansion of your solution.

Comment: There is FindOpenMP cmake module. See http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindOpenMP.html

Comment: @GradGuy I am using CMake 3.7 and clang 4.0 but my `find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)` fails to find OpenMP.

Comment: @DavidDoria Clang used to have problems with OpenMP, specially on OSX, but it looks like the new version should work fine. Can you build a simple OpenMP test with your version of clang?

Comment: @GradGuy You mean with Clang I don't even have to `find_package(OpenMP)`?

Answer (score 36):

CMake has a FindOpenMP module even in 2.x versions. See http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindOpenMP.html

So I'll do this:

```
OPTION (USE_OpenMP "Use OpenMP" ON)
IF(USE_OpenMP)
  FIND_PACKAGE(OpenMP)
  IF(OPENMP_FOUND)
    SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
  ENDIF()
ENDIF()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Exactly what I needed :D

Answer (score 15):

According to the [Modern CMake](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/packages/OpenMP.html) online book, this is how you configure OpenMP support with CMake:

```
find_package(OpenMP)
if(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(MyTarget PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
endif()
```

What you *definitely should not do* is to add flags like `-fopenmp` manually (like the accepted answer recommends) because that may not be portable.

Comment: This is the ONLY correct answer on this page.

Comment: The pastes cmake lines is cool, brief, portable. However, it failed on my qnx-aarch64 compiler, it just don't know where the openmp shared or static library locates, but I know where they are. What's worse, I can't tell CMake to find them! What a joke.

Comment: That only sets the link libraries. My cmake successfully finds OpenMP, but does not add a flag to the compile line.

Answer (score 0):

iNFINITEi's answer doesn't work for me. 
I use Ubuntu, trying to compile some code with `OpenCV` static library. After linking, I got this:

> '"/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(parallel.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol 'omp_set_dynamic@@OMP_1.0'"'

So I tried iNFINITEi's approach, then I have:

> 'CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:211 (message):
>     No REQUIRED_VARS specified for FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS()
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     /usr/local/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake:513 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
>     CMakeLists.txt:8 (FIND_PACKAGE)'

At last, I add `"-fopenmp=libomp"` to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, solved my problem.

Answer (score -5):

You should install libomp with brew install libomp

i use macOS and it worked smoothly for me.

Comment: No. It's built into every compiler.