# CMake Could NOT find OpenMP in Clion

Tags: macos, gcc, openmp, clion

I am trying to compile an OpenMP prject in Clion on Mac.

I have tried

[How to set up basic openMP project in CLion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531078/how-to-set-up-basic-openmp-project-in-clion/40534056#40534056)

[How to set linker flags for OpenMP in CMake's try_compile function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399422/how-to-set-linker-flags-for-openmp-in-cmakes-try-compile-function/12404666#12404666)

[CMake cannot find OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633513/cmake-cannot-find-openmp)

But they all don't work for me. Clion just says:

-- Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES)

-- Could NOT find OpenMP_CXX (missing: OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES)

-- Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_C_FOUND OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)

I also tried compile it using "gcc -o main -fopenmp main.c" in the command line and it works fine.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main() {
printf("Hello, World!\n");
#pragma omp parallel
printf("Hello world from thread %d\n",omp_get_thread_num());
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know it's silly, but I had a very similar error (which I why I found this question), and just solved it by deleting everything in the build directory. I'm using a simple CMake project, but clion should be the same.

Comment: @mjgalindo Actually, CLion caches all of this configuration in the build directory.  I faced the same issue as above despite having another CLion project running on the same machine with OpenMP.  I can confirm that, after deleting *everything* in the build directory, you must `Reload CMake Project` and verify that it retrieves the OpenMP configuration.  Then you can build the project as usual.