# include_dirs for OpenMP in CMakeLists

Tags: c++, cmake, openmp

I met a project which enable omp and has this line of code in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CUR_DIR} /usr/lib/llvm-11/include/openmp/)
```

and I tried to make it more general like:

```
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
if (OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
  include_directories(${CMAKE_CUR_DIR) ${OpenMP_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()
```

but the `OpenMP_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS` is still a empty string and the code using `include <omp.h>` still throw an error, how can I do this?

I tried `message(STATUS "${OpenMP_C_INCLUDE_DIRS}")` it still a empty string.

Comment: What is this `CMAKE_CUR_DIR`? Did you mean to use: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html

Comment: Most compilers support OpenMP by some flag, which automatically adds OpenMP include directories. That is, after the call to `find_package(OpenMP)` you need to consume not only `OpenMP_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable, but `OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS` too. It is simpler, however, to link with corresponding IMPORTED target (`OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX` for C++ language).

Answer (score 1):

`include_directories` is old cmake API and is should not be used in now.

This should be enough to make it work (didn't test it, done base on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67487146/1387438)):

```
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)

add_exectuable(YourExecutable)
target_link_libraries(YourExecutable PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
```

Since you are using `REQUIRED` flag the `if` check is not needed (error will be reported if library can't be found).