# OpenMP_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS is not filled in by CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, openmp

I am using OpenMP to parallelize `for` loops in my program. I would like to not only do that but also use functions that are declared in <omp.h> which I inlude using `#include <omp.h>`. In my IDE, that include line is highlighted with error `omp.h file not found` (should be if the include dir were set somewhere because I use compile_commands.json).

I use the FindOpenMP.cmake file in the form of `find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)`, and that call is successful, with flags correctly set both at compile time and link time. I looked at the value of ${OpenMP_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS}, and that is empty. I need that value in a portable way so as to #include the header file with no error message.

I am aware of this question: [include_dirs for OpenMP in CMakeLists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76754274/include-dirs-for-openmp-in-cmakelists), but that does not answer this question.

Any help ?
Sincerely,
Filippo

Comment: are you linking to `OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX`? Does the code compile? If it does then it sounds like its a problem with your IDE configuration. Please show a [mre]

Comment: @Alan Birtles: thank you for your answer. Yes I do link with OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX, but this is not the problem. My code checker is based on Clang. Clang does not know where the omp.h header is (compiling using g++).  The code checker uses compile_commands.json, which is filled using CMake upon configuration of the project. That file contains all the include dirs needed to build the whole project. But since find_package(OpenMP) does not fill that OpenMP_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS variable, then I cannot aggregate these include directories to CMake, which in turn does'nt write them in compile_commands.json.

Comment: Cmake will just be writing the commands it's running into `compile_commands.json`, if your ide can't handle that it's a bug in your ide. Again [edit] a [mre] into your question with all the details necessary to reproduce your problem

Comment: I have been debuggin line-by-line the FindOpenMP.cmake file and discovered that it was crafted for Intel, Clang and Clang-Apple compilers, not for GCC (gcc or g++). The OpenMP_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS is never filled-up. But I noticed that the omp.h header comes with gcc/g++ and is located in an 'include' directory itself located in the directory that contains libgomp.so. That directory is documented in the OpenMP_CXX_LIBRARIES variable after the find_package(OpenMP) call. A bit of CMake script-fu and I could write the proper contents for the OpenMP_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS variable. Solved.