# cmake: how to add a compiler flag according to current compiler version

Tags: gcc, cmake

I have a c library to maintain, which is built by cmake.
When I start to build it, it tells me that

```
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-incompatible-pointer-types" [enabled by default]
```

yes, my gcc version is 4.8.5 and does not have that flag.
So I want to disable it when the compiler does not support that flag.

After some searching, I came to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134660/how-to-apply-different-compiler-options-for-different-compilers-in-cmake)

```
include(CheckCCompilerFlag)
check_c_compiler_flag(-Wno-invalid-offsetof HAS_NO_INVALID_OFFSETOF)
if (HAS_NO_INVALID_OFFSETOF)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-invalid-offsetof")
endif()
```

but when I add it to my CMakeLists.txt, it does not work, the above warning still comes out.

After searching the cmake documentation, it tells me that

> A positive result from this check indicates only that the compiler did not issue a diagnostic message when given the flag. Whether the flag has any effect or even a specific one is beyond the scope of this module.

According to that, my gcc does not support that flag, it won't issue a diagnostic message, so cmake thinks that my gcc supports that flag?

Is there any way to make it act as the way I like it to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from `man gcc`

> When an unrecognized warning option is requested (e.g., `-Wunknown-warning`), GCC emits a diagnostic stating that the option is not recognized.  However, if the `-Wno-` form is used, the behavior is slightly different: no diagnostic is produced for `-Wno-unknown-warning` unless other diagnostics are being produced.  This allows the use of new `-Wno-` options with old compilers, but if something goes wrong, the compiler warns that an unrecognized option is present.

You could modify your check to the following

```
include(CheckCCompilerFlag)
check_c_compiler_flag(-Winvalid-offsetof HAS_INVALID_OFFSETOF)
if (HAS_INVALID_OFFSETOF)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-invalid-offsetof")
endif()
```

This could theoretially break for some non-gcc compiler which happens to support `-Winvalid-offsetof` but not `-Wno-invalid-offsetof`. So if you want to be extra safe, add another check.